# Is it safe to set interestOps of SelectionKey in other thread than selector thread? (Java Nio)

Tags: java, nio

I have seen many JavaNio examples. All of them set interestOps of SelectionKey in selector thread.

Why they do it?
Is it safe to set interestOps of SelectionKey in other thread than selector thread?

Or there are abnormal situations that can occur, so they do it?

Comment: The Javadoc explicitly talks about thread safety guarantees offered by the `SelectionKey` so there doesn't seem to be such a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SelectionKey JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html) says this:

> The operations of reading and writing the interest set will, in general, be synchronized with certain operations of the selector. Exactly how this synchronization is performed is implementation-dependent: In a naive implementation, reading or writing the interest set may block indefinitely if a selection operation is already in progress; in a high-performance implementation, reading or writing the interest set may block briefly, if at all.

Combined with Murphy's law it practically guaranties that you will encounter only "naïve" implementations, so it is better to be safe than sorry and work with interest ops only from the selector thread, where they are guaranteed not to block.

Comment: I would still wait for the practice to prove Murphy's law in this case. The idioms may come from a time where this was a problem, but has long disappeared. You don't exactly encounter random NIO implementations.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sun/Oracle implementation in Java 6/7/8 simply updates volatile field without obtaining any locks, so technically it is safe to read/write interest ops from other threads when running on these JVMs. I assume that non-Oracle JVMs actually do the same, but javadoc still implies that interest ops modification can block, and does not provide a way to check beforehand whether it is blocking operation or not. Know your target environment - modify from anywhere, otherwise take javadoc to the letter and modify from selector thread only.

Comment: That's exactly the right attitude: if you are writing a public, widely applicable API, code defensively; otherwise don't let irrelevant concerns mutillate your code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to set interestOps of SelectionKey in other thread than selector thread

By safe, I presume you mean multi-thread safe.
A: Yes.  In fact, it is common (I'm not sure what NIO code you've looked at)

> Or there are abnormal situations that can occur, so they do it?

A.  Yes, specifically it *may* block **iff the selector thread is in a blocking select() call**
Now, in most cases this is not a practical concern, because for busy servers select() calls *return immediately* (more or less)
Why? Because there is always at least one Channel that has bytes to be read
The issue is that even busy servers aren't always busy (say at 2:00 am), and in that case a Reader thread (not the Selector thread), could theoretically block forever (it's a race condition)
So there are a couple of practices that can mitigate (although not eliminate) the race condition:

1. Have the Selector thread always use timed select(long ms) calls
2. Have Reader threads do:

   ```
   key.selector().wakeup()
   key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ)
   ```

This in practice makes it extremely unlikely that Reader threads will block for very long

Frankly it's not ideal (IMO interestOps() should not be allowed to block), but better than the alternatives